# Debian - limiting access for admin users

Tags: linux, debian, sysadmin

I'm small company owner, currently managing about 15 Debian based boxes, providing VoIP and hosted PBX services

Company is growing, I have less time to manage all of that machines

I'd like to hire system administrator, but I have a strong fear of giving root access to the stranger.

Many things could go wrong, he can make mistakes, he can install backdoors. It's not about broken system. Mis-managed VoIP server could lead to significant loss due tool fraud, premium number calls and so on. Loss can go in millions.

I have read posts stating that I must have level of trust, and if someone will make damage, than I can sue him. But that's not the case for SMB. In such situation my company will bankrupt before first court session.

Before down-voting - This problem is for sure not new or unique, but I haven't found on serverfalut information that is recent, can be applied to Debian servers and relies on software with licence costs that my small business can afford. So currently I see no duplicate thread.

No-root access is probably not going to be productive, I can't imagine resolving any serious system problems without root. Maybe I'm wrong?

What strategies can be used in this situation?
Is there any software that could help?

Comment: Trust as in "this person knows how to do the job and has the skills" or trust as in "how do I know this guy won't do something evil" ?

Comment: It is said that with great power (to administer a system) comes great responsibility (to not screw it up). I don't think there's a way around that.